# Set font size using size classes programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, size-classes, adaptive-layout

There are a few posts on this, but none seem to have a complete solution.

Using adaptive layout via IB I can easily change font sizes for specific size classes, however I have a custom view using UILabels and I want to programmatically set the font size depending on the size class in use (using swift) - Has anyone else had this issue or come across a solution?

Comment: what do you mean by "size class in use"?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528661/ios-detect-current-size-classes-on-viewdidload

Comment: I mean , how to detect if the height/width is compact or regular i.e using Adaptive Layout programmatically rather than setting it up via the IB

Answer (score 1):

You need your custom view to override `traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)` from the [UITraitEnvironment Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITraitEnvironment) that UIView conforms to.

> **Discussion**
>
> The system calls this method when the iOS interface
> environment changes. Implement this method in view controllers and
> views, according to your app’s needs, to respond to such changes. For
> example, you might adjust the layout of the subviews of a view
> controller when an iPhone is rotated from portrait to landscape
> orientation. The default implementation of this method is empty.

You may have to observe height/width for the iPad size class: Regular| Regular

Answer (score 1):

Your custom view (UIView) has a `traitCollection` property that has the `size classes` information. Check out the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795175/2503640